# react-native-file-viewer not working on Android 11

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-file-viewer on android to open pdf files. It is working fine on Android 10 but gives error "No app associated with this mime type" on Android 11 and opened google play store to download an app with mime: application/pdf.
If I download any app it still redirects me to app store the next time.
Please help